# Ember - How to pass selected option value as parameter to action handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to ember. Can anyone help me how to pass selected value as parameter to action handler 'onSelectEntityType'. I have tried the following and I am able to trigger the action.

```
<select class="form-control" id="entityType" {{action 'onSelectEntityType' on='change'}} >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    {{#each model as |entityType|}}
    <option value="{{entityType.id}}">{{entityType.entityTypeName}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

**Component js file**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions: {
      onSelectEntityType(value) {
         console.log(value)
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Ember 1.13.3 or later, you can do:

```
<select class="form-control" id="entityType" onchange={{action 'onSelectEntityType' value="target.value"}} >
  <option value="">Select</option>
  {{#each model as |entityType|}}
    <option value="{{entityType.id}}">{{entityType.entityTypeName}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

For a better explanation than I could provide, see: http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. It worked. 

Previously I tried  {{action 'onSelectEntityType' value="target.value" on='change'}}, but that didnt worked.

Comment: @Gaurav, any idea how we can do this in ember 1.11?

Comment: @whyAto8 You had to use {{view 'select'}}

Comment: Well, I didnt, because we had plans to upgrade ember soon, and i saw that it is deprecated.

Comment: Link is dead (padding to appease S.O.)

Answer (score 1):

The way Ember deals with `<select>` has changed since 1.13. Using HTMLBars allows us to now directly add an action to the `onchange` property. As far as passing the value, you can do this by passing `target.value` to your action:

```
<select onchange={{action 'onSelectEntityType' value="target.value"}} >
```

[Here's a sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c23b7af81333ab70c4fb)

Answer (score 1):

in ember octane

```
//component template  file
<select  {{on "change" this.setItemValue}}>
  {{#each @items as |item|}}
  <option value={{item}}>{{item}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>


 // component class file
 @action
  setItemValue(evt) {
    let itemValue = evt.target.value;
    evt.preventDefault();

  }
```